# linux setup pptp vpn programmatically

Tags: linux, vpn

I'd like to setup PPTP VPN connection in a C code under Linux. And then monitor its state, when it got offline, I want to reconnect it. But I haven't found any api for doing this. Is there any api or library to achieve this? Or any other alternative methods?

Comment: I believe you should be able to do this with dbus calls to network-manager with the network-manager-pptp plugin if you have the right libraries installed. Otherwise you're going to have to do it by hand and exec the right daemons yourself in your C code.

Comment: I just think of this way. But I don't know how to figure out which virtual device is the one created when I setup a connection. I have other pppoe connection which also creates device like ppp+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following shell command to setup pptp vpn in my code.

```
pppd pty "pptp <vpn-host> --nolaunchpppd" user <vpn-user> password <vpn-password> lock noauth nobsdcomp nodeflate nodetach
```

The last option tells pppd not to run as a daemon. Then I can disconnect the vpn by killing the specific process of pppd.

And reading for the pppd standard output stream, you can get the more information about the vpn connection, like the virtual device, local-ip, remote-ip and so forth.